# Spring Data JPA + Spring Batch + Hibernate and Bidirectional @OneToMany relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

I'm seeing inconsistent behavior with standard practices and persisting JPA bidirectional relationships through Spring Data JPA as part of Spring Batch job. I have a job with steps that look like the following:

```
@Bean
public Step importSinglePatient(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                ItemReader<Patient> singlePatientReader,
                                ItemWriter<Patient> patientWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("importSinglePatient")
        .<Patient, Patient>chunk(1)
        .reader(singlePatientReader)
        .writer(patientWriter)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Step importSingleEncounter(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                  ItemReader<Encounter> singleEncounterReader,
                                  ItemWriter<Encounter> encounterWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("importSingleEncounter")
        .<Encounter, Encounter>chunk(1)
        .reader(singleEncounterReader)
        .writer(encounterWriter)
        .build();
}
```

The two domains are `Patient` (parent) and `Encounter` (child). They look like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Patient implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long patientId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Encounter> encounters;

    // getters & setters
}

@Entity
public class Encounter implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long encounterId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private Patient patient;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Next, assume that all of the patients have been read in from the source database and persisted as part of a previous step. The next step that executes reads in all of the Encounters (children) via a `JdbcPagingItemReader<Encounter>` with a `RowMapper<Encounter>`. The `RowMapper` code looks like the following:

```
@Component
public class EncounterRowMapper implements RowMapper<Encounter> {

    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientRepository

    public static final String PATIENT_ID = "PATIENT_ID";

    @Override
    public Encounter mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Encounter encounter = new Encounter;
        Patient patient = patientRepository.findOne(rs.getLong(PATIENT_ID));
        encounter.setPatient(patient);
        return encounter;
    }
}
```

The `Encounter` is then passed to a `RepositoryItemWriter<Encounter>` that saves the Encounter to the `EncounterRepository`.

My understanding is that this isn't best practice for the following reasons:

1. I should be doing a `patient.getEncounters.add(encounter)`; however, I don't think this fits well with what a RowMapper should be doing. Maybe I'm wrong here. Could move this to an `ItemProcessor<Encounter, Patient>` and change the `ItemWriter` to an `ItemWriter<Patient>` instead. I would be constantly persisting my parents, though, which isn't ideal if the child is the owner of the relationship -- nor is the parent ever changing.
2. I'm very likely to see Hibernate caching issues by not doing #1. This doesn't seem to be the case. I've confirmed via my Spring MVC controlled that the parent and child relationships look as expected across all of my domains (including the one above) after the job completes and without doing `patient.getEncounters.add(encounter)` anywhere in my code.
3. I have a lot of bidirectional relationships throughout this application. I've read bidirectional relationships are bad and should be replaced with repositories, but I don't see a good way to do that with Spring Batch's `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, and `ItemWriter` model.

Hoping someone can help me understand why I'm not seeing #2 and thoughts on #1 & #3.

Comment: You realize that the item returned from your `ItemReader` is not associated with hibernate until you use the `RepositoryItemWriter` to persist it, correct?    It's just a regular POJO at that point.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm trying to understand the consequences of not doing patient.getEncounters.add(encounter) anywhere in my code for the other side of the bidirectional relationship. Adding the encounter to the list is nowhere in my code, and yet I still see the expected behavior of my relationships through my controller after the Encounter is persisted.

Comment: Bidirectional relationships are a concept in OO code...not relational databases.  When you retrieve the new object, your JPA provider (assuming Hibernate) handles the additional stuff for you.

Comment: Fair enough. Looks like I was overthinking this one.